# What exactly is the long chain band?

Tags: hydrocarbons, ir-spectroscopy

I have progressed quite enough in infrared spectroscopy, and now I'm looking at the spectrum of alkanes in detail. I found out that straight chain alkanes have this **long chain band** in the spectrum:

[image]

<sub>The infrared spectrum of decane. Taken from: *Introduction to Spectroscopy*, Pavia et. al.</sub>

On the other hand, cyclic one's don't have this band:

[image]

<sub>The infrared spectrum of cyclohexane. Taken from: *Introduction to Spectroscopy*, Pavia et. al.</sub>

I also found this info in my book:

> $\ce{CH2}$ - The bending (rocking) motion associated with four or more $\ce{CH2}$ groups in an open chain occurs at about $\pu{720cm^-1}$ (called a *long-chain band).

I am still perplexed. Why can't the $\ce{CH2}$ groups in the cyclic chains undergo rocking vibrations? Why is this specific to the open chained ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'long chain band' described in your textbook (Pavia) is actually a vibrational mode in which the terminal methyl groups are 'rocking'.

This rocking mode is observed in open chain alkanes,  -(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>-, where the number of methylene units is greater than 4.

Polyethylene is the '*classic*' examples, the IR spectra and corresponding vibrational modes are given below:

[image]

[image]

**Why do we see this band?**

The reason we see **any** given IR band is as a consequence of the symmetry of the molecule, with only certain molecular vibrations IR active (we don't, for example, observe the C-C vibrations directly, they aren't active). Your question, more broadly, then becomes 'how to predict the IR active vibrational modes for a given molecule?'.

For a full explanation of the IR spectra in this particular case, using molecular symmetry and group theory, you might try reading *J. Chem. Phys* **1956**, *25*, 549.

**Why don't we see the band in cyclic alkanes?**

In cyclic alkanes, the methyl groups have been constrained to form one continuous ring of methylene groups. As discussed above, the band at ~725 cm<sup>-1</sup> is caused by the terminal methyl groups of longer chain alkanes, hence, removing these methyl groups removes their corresponding vibrational modes.